# Pretty SSH client for OSX?

Tags: gui, openssh

I know cyberduck is a good ftp/sftp client, but what about a pretty ssh client that is at least separate from the terminal.  I want to be able to leave it running with a reverse ssh tunnel so that I can access my dorm room computer from anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fugu](http://rsug.itd.umich.edu/software/fugu/)? It's a bit old but you can manage SSH tunnels in it. Maybe also [SSH Tunnel Manager](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/stm/) which is also old; I would recommend getting the 2.0b3 version.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to leave this open a bit longer just in case there are any more recommendations.

Answer (score 6):

Call me old fashioned:
But what is so bad about using the ssh client from the command line?

```
ssh user@host -L 8080:server:80
```

You could then put that in a script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ssh user@host -L 8080:server:80
```

If you are THAT attached to the GUI - I think putty is your answer:
http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=putty

Comment: haha I have no problem with using bash.  I use it for most things.  However, I want something that my room mate could use and fix if things go wrong while I'm not around.

Comment: Linking to darwinports.com is misleading since that site has nothing to do with the MacPorts package management system and will ask you for your name and email address to be informed when "Darwinports will be available". Either link to MacPorts at http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=putty or the PuTTY home page at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Comment: @fideli - Totally my bad and will edit. I do not own a Mac so I could only hope that was the official location for it.

Answer (score 3):

[meerkat](http://codesorcery.net/meerkat) is the prettiest of the ssh tunnel managers

Comment: Wow, looks pretty slick!